# May a query update a source table?

Tags: ms-access

I work with a few tables with given data. I run a query built in Design View just like 
`result:![table1].[qty]*![table2].[expenses]` 
and I get the output in query table in field `result`. Is it possible to write `result` back to `table2.resultfield`? So this way my query does not only produce output table but updates one of the source tables.

Comment: I suspect that this question should be on Stackoverflow

Comment: I could remove this question. Thanks for advices. Just found a solution for Q

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update a field in the underlying table of a form when the control is bound to a function (a calculation in this case). However, you can run an update query, use VBA to update the field, use VBA to write the calculation to a bound control, or use a calculated field (MS Access 2010 and later versions only).

However, you must ask yourself if you really want to store a calculated result. It will depend on whether qty and expenses change over time and whether you need a fixed result for the current values. If qty and expenses will always be the same, just use a query to show the result of the calculation. For example:

```
SELECT t1.qty * t2.expenses As Total
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.MatchedID
```

Comment: In fact. You are right about need to think choice beetwen simple output query use